# On generalizing Partition[] (with offsets) to sublists of unequal length

Tags: list-manipulation

The usual `Partition[]` function is a very handy little thing:

```
Partition[Range[12], 4]
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}}

Partition[Range[13], 4, 3]
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {10, 11, 12, 13}}
```

One application I'm working on required me to write a particular generalization of `Partition[]`'s functionality, which allowed the generation of sublists of unequal lengths, for as long as the lengths were appropriately commensurate. (Let's assume for the purposes of this question that the list lengths being commensurate is guaranteed, but you're welcome to generalize further to the incommensurate case.) Here's my generalization in action:

```
multisegment[lst_List, scts_List] := Block[{acc},
  acc = Prepend[Accumulate[PadRight[scts, Length[lst]/Mean[scts], scts]], 0];
  Inner[Take[lst, {#1, #2}] &, Most[acc] + 1, Rest[acc], List]]

multisegment[CharacterRange["a", "x"], {3, 1, 2}]
{{"a", "b", "c"}, {"d"}, {"e", "f"}, {"g", "h", "i"}, {"j"}, {"k", "l"},
 {"m", "n", "o"}, {"p"}, {"q", "r"}, {"s", "t", "u"}, {"v"}, {"w", "x"}}
```

(Thanks to halirutan for optimization help with `multisegment[]`.)

The problem I've hit into is that I wanted `multisegment[]` to also support offsets, just like in `Partition[]`. I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
multisegment[Range[14], {4, 3}, {3, 1}]
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, 
 {8, 9, 10}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {12, 13, 14}}
```

How might a version of `multisegment[]` with offsets be accomplished?

Comment: why `Block` rather than `Module`?

Comment: @Mike, no good reason; it could just as well be `Module[]` in there...

Comment: What is your application for this?

Comment: @Mike: I'm using this to build lattices. The idea is to generate a series of points by rows, and then take the appropriate amount of points from two consecutive rows to build a tile.

Comment: Could tell me what the argument `scts` mean? Namely, which word's `abbreviation` is `scts`?

Comment: @Shutao, note the output of `multisegment[CharacterRange["a", "x"], {3, 1, 2}]`. The result is a list of lists with lengths $3,1,2$ repeating up until the  contents of the original list are exhausted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This is a complete re-write**

This is the original solution which was done in haste but i will leave here. It works in limited cases:

```
multisegment[lst_List, scts_List, offset_List] := 
 Module[{acc, offs}, 
  offs = 1+Prepend[Accumulate[PadRight[offset, 
      1 + Ceiling[Length[lst]/Total[offset]], offset]], 0];
  acc = PadRight[scts, Length[offs],scts];
  acc = acc + offs - 1;
  Inner[Take[lst, {#1, #2}] &, offs, acc, List]
  ]

multisegment[Range[14], {4, 3}, {3, 1}]
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {8, 9, 10}, {9, 10, 11, 
  12}, {12, 13, 14}}
```

To solve this you note that the starting position (for `Part` or `Take`) of the list depends solely on the offset list:

```
{1,4,5,8,9,12}
```

The "span to" position is determined by adding the partition list

```
{4,3,4,3,4,3}
```

to the offset list (minus 1) to give

```
{4,6,8,10,12,14}
```

From there, proceed as before with `Inner` and use either `Take` or `Part`. So this becomes an exercise in generating the correct offset list. As earlier failed attempts have shown, this is dependent on both the total of the offsets and the length of the offsets (list).

But also you do not want your `Take` or "span to" range exceeding the length of your target list. I have taken the easy way out here but using `DeleteCases`. A more exact and possibly elegant, but maybe not faster (?), approach is to actually work this out based on the partition list.

```
multisegment[lst_List, scts_List, offset_List] := 
 Module[{fin, offs, len = Length[lst], tot = Total[offset], len2 = Length[offset]}, 
  offs = 1 + Prepend[Accumulate[
      PadRight[offset, Ceiling[len2*len/tot], offset]], 0];
  fin = PadRight[scts, Length[offs], scts] + offs - 1;
  fin = DeleteCases[Transpose[{offs, fin}], {_, x_ /; x > len}];
  Take[lst, #] & /@ fin]

 (* case for no offsets *)
 multisegment[lst_List, scts_List] := multisegment[lst, scts, scts]
```

I prefer to layout the code in steps rather than combine multiple steps into a one (or two) liner. Feel free to do that if you wish but I think this way makes it easier for people to check out what is happening.

Also a qualifier: checks and/or conditions should be added. you cannot have {0} for your partition or offset. Must be integers etc. as per Simon's comments.

Usage. First the base case of an uneven partition with no offset

```
multisegment[Range[14], {3, 4}]
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14}}
```

now add an offset

```
multisegment[Range[14], {3, 4}, {1, 2}]
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {7, 8, 9}, {8, 9, 
  10, 11}, {10, 11, 12}, {11, 12, 13, 14}}
```

Examples that previously failed:

```
multisegment[Range[10], {5, 4}, {2, 3}]
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}

multisegment[Range[100], {5, 4}, {2, 3}]
{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {8, 9, 10, 11}, {11,
   12, 13, 14, 15}, {13, 14, 15, 16}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, {18, 19, 
  20, 21}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}, {23, 24, 25, 26}, {26, 27, 28, 29, 
  30}, {28, 29, 30, 31}, {31, 32, 33, 34, 35}, {33, 34, 35, 36}, {36, 
  37, 38, 39, 40}, {38, 39, 40, 41}, {41, 42, 43, 44, 45}, {43, 44, 
  45, 46}, {46, 47, 48, 49, 50}, {48, 49, 50, 51}, {51, 52, 53, 54, 
  55}, {53, 54, 55, 56}, {56, 57, 58, 59, 60}, {58, 59, 60, 61}, {61, 
  62, 63, 64, 65}, {63, 64, 65, 66}, {66, 67, 68, 69, 70}, {68, 69, 
  70, 71}, {71, 72, 73, 74, 75}, {73, 74, 75, 76}, {76, 77, 78, 79, 
  80}, {78, 79, 80, 81}, {81, 82, 83, 84, 85}, {83, 84, 85, 86}, {86, 
  87, 88, 89, 90}, {88, 89, 90, 91}, {91, 92, 93, 94, 95}, {93, 94, 
  95, 96}, {96, 97, 98, 99, 100}}
```

Example showing it working with increasing offset list length

```
multisegment[Range[44], {3, 4}, {1, 3, 2}]
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {8, 9, 10}, {11, 
  12, 13, 14}, {13, 14, 15}, {14, 15, 16, 17}, {17, 18, 19}, {19, 20, 
  21, 22}, {20, 21, 22}, {23, 24, 25, 26}, {25, 26, 27}, {26, 27, 28, 
  29}, {29, 30, 31}, {31, 32, 33, 34}, {32, 33, 34}, {35, 36, 37, 
  38}, {37, 38, 39}, {38, 39, 40, 41}, {41, 42, 43}}

multisegment[Range[44], {3, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4}]
{{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 6, 7}, {7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13}, {12,
   13, 14, 15}, {15, 16, 17}, {17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23}, {22, 23,
   24, 25}, {25, 26, 27}, {27, 28, 29, 30}, {31, 32, 33}, {32, 33, 34,
   35}, {35, 36, 37}, {37, 38, 39, 40}, {41, 42, 43}}
```

and so on, and so forth.

Comment: `multisegment[Range[10], {5, 4}, {2, 3}]` *almost* gives the right answer...

Comment: that broke because `Take` was trying to take a position beyond the length of the list. Now fixed.

Comment: You new code does not generate the entire set of partitions. Try the example `multisegment[Range[100], {5, 4}, {2, 3}]`

Comment: fixed. just needed to modify the pad right length.

Comment: Nice generalization! :)

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, Hi, I have understood your program by execute every step. However, I'd like to know what the argument `scts` mean? Namely, which word's `abbreviation` is `scts`. In addition, I don't quite understand `Ceiling[len2*len/tot]`.

Comment: @Tangshutao scts is simply reused from the OP

Answer (score 3):

Here's my version using the `Sow` and `Reap` combination.

```
multisegment::arglen = 
  "The argument `1` is not of the same length as the argument `2`.";

multisegment[lst_List, scts_List, offsets_List] := 
 Module[{len = Length[lst], slen = Length[scts], i = 1, j = 1}, 
   Reap[If[slen =!= Length[offsets],
     Message[multisegment::arglen, scts, offsets]; Sow[$Failed],
     Do[Sow[Take[lst, {i, i + scts[[j]] - 1}]];
      i = i + offsets[[j]]; j = Mod[j + 1, slen, 1];
      If[i + scts[[j]] - 1 > len, Break[]],
      {len/Total[offsets]*slen}]]]][[2, 1]]
multisegment[lst_List, scts_List] := multisegment[lst, scts, scts]
```

Note that you should also add checks to make sure that the `scts` and `offsets` arguments are all integers and that `Total[offsets] > 0` etc...

---

Here's the relative timings (using my `TimeAv` code) for running

```
multisegment[Range[n], {4, 3}, {3, 1}]; // TimeAv
```

with various values of `n` and the different solutions presented so far. 
The timing of my version of `multisegment` is normalised to 1.

```
                Mike H    Heike    

n = 200        0.488689, 2.17595 

n = 20 000     0.444445, 4.00373

n = 200 000    0.495761, 54.6492
```

Comment: Maybe someone could test the "fastest" way to apply the conditions: partition list and offset list must be one or more positive integers.

Answer (score 3):

My first method was related to Mike's, yet unrefined.  This is another method designed for speed.  As written it only returns the portion of the list which can be partitioned into a complete set of partitions.  This behavior can be changed with 4th+ argument of `Partition` and/or filtering.

```
dpCyclic[l_List, p : {__Integer?Positive}, {os__Integer?Positive}] :=
  Module[{ranges, blocks},
    ranges = {# + 1, # + p} & @ Most @ Accumulate @ {0, os};
    blocks = Partition[l, Max @ Last @ ranges, +os];
    MapThread[blocks[[All, # ;; #2]] &, ranges] ~Flatten~ {2, 1}
  ]
```

As an example of different behavior (with implicit `Null`s):

```
dpCyclic[l_List, p : {__Integer?Positive}, {os__Integer?Positive}] :=
  Module[{ranges, blocks},
    ranges = {# + 1, # + p} & @ Most @ Accumulate @ {0, os};
    blocks = Partition[l, Max @ Last @ ranges, +os, 1,];
    MapThread[blocks[[All, # ;; #2]] &, ranges] ~Flatten~ {2, 1} ~DeleteCases~ {___,}
  ]
```

Comment: Dear Mr.Wizard, In `blocks = Partition[l, Max @ Last @ ranges, +os]`, I cannot understand the `+os`, I execute it and give the result 4 (Assuming that the `dpCyclic[Range@14, {4,3}, {3,1}]`)

Comment: @Tangshutao That's some of my devious shorthand. :o)  It evaluates as `Plus[os]`.  Please see: [(31797)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31797), then also these other examples:  [(5038)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5038), [(27554)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/27554), [(30240)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30240),
[(52318)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/52318),
[(56670)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/56670)

Comment: OK, thanks sincerely :-)

Answer (score 3):

Also related to Mike's solution:

```
ClearAll[irregPartition];
irregPartition[list_List, sizes_List, offsets_List] := 
  Module[{offsetlist, sizelist},
   offsetlist = (NestWhile[Join[offsets, #] &,offsets, (Tr@# < Length@list) &] //
     NestWhile[Most, #, (Tr@# >= Length@list) &] & // Accumulate //
    Prepend[#, 0] & ) + 1;
 sizelist = NestWhile[Join[sizes, #] &,sizes,(Length@# <= Length@offsetlist) &] //
 NestWhile[Most, #, Length@# > Length@offsetlist &] &;
{offsetlist, sizelist} =Transpose@TakeWhile[
  Partition[Riffle[offsetlist, sizelist], 2], #[[1]] + #[[2]] <= Length@list &];
MapThread[Take[#1,Min[#2, Length@#1]] &, {Drop[list, 
     Min[#, Length@list]] & /@ (offsetlist - 1), sizelist}] // 
If[Length@Last@# < Last@sizelist, Most@#, #] &];

irregPartition[list_List, sizes_List] := irregPartition[list, sizes, sizes];
```

Example:

```
list = Range[10];
sizes = {5, 4};
offsets = {2, 3};
irregPartition[list, sizes, offsets]
(* 
==> {{1,2,3,4,5},{3,4,5,6},{6,7,8,9,10}}
*)
irregPartition[list, sizes]
(*
==> {{1,2,3,4,5},{6,7,8,9}
*)
```

Another example:

```
list = CharacterRange["a", "x"];
sizes = {4, 5, 3, 4};
offsets = {2, 7, 3, 5};
irregPartition[list, sizes, offsets]
(*
 ==> {{"a","b","c","d"},{"c","d","e","f","g"},{"j","k","l"},{"m","n","o","p"},{"r","s","t","u"},{"t","u","v","w","x"}}
*)
irregPartition[list, sizes]
(*
==> {{"a","b","c","d"},{"e","f","g","h","i"},{"j","k","l"},{"m","n","o","p"},{"q","r","s","t"}}
*)
```

Comment: `irregPartition[list, sizes, offsets]` ==> `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {3, 4, 5, 6}}` not the result `{{1,2,3,4,5},{3,4,5,6},{6,7,8,9,10}}` that your answer gives. In addition, `list = CharacterRange["a", "x"];
sizes = {4, 5, 3, 4};
offsets = {2, 7, 3, 5};
irregPartition[list, sizes, offsets]` cannot achieve the result that you give

Comment: @Tangshutao, right. I think this was posted two versions ago; need to check what has changed since version 8:)

Comment: Ok,thanks sincerely.:-)

Answer (score 2):

Whit solution is using a `NestWhile` construction in combination with `Sow` and `Reap`

```
partitions[list_, {parts_List, offsets_List}] :=
  Reap[
    NestWhile[{RotateLeft[#[[1]]], RotateLeft[#[[2]]], 
      Sow[#[[3]][[;; #[[1, 1]]]]]; ArrayPad[#[[3]], {-#[[2, 1]], 0}]} &,
     {parts, offsets, list},
     (Length[#[[3]]] >= #[[1, 1]]) &];
  ][[2, 1]]

partitions[list_, p : {__?NumericQ}] := partitions[list, {p, p}]
```

Example

```
list = CharacterRange["a", "z"];

partitions[list, {{3, 4}, {1, 3}}]
```

> ```
>  {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"b", "c", "d", "e"}, {"e", "f", "g"}, 
>   {"f", "g", "h", "i"}, {"i", "j", "k"}, {"j", "k", "l", "m"}, 
>   {"m", "n", "o"}, {"n", "o", "p", "q"}, {"q", "r", "s"}, 
>   {"r", "s", "t", "u"}, {"u", "v", "w"}, {"v", "w", "x", "y"}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to slightly build on Mike's answer. There's a minimum (i.e., woefully incomplete) amount of checking done, but it should mostly work:

```
multisegment[lst_List, scts:{__Integer?Positive}, offset:{__Integer?NonNegative}]:= 
 Module[{n = Length[lst], k, offs},
   k = Ceiling[n/Mean[offset]];
   offs = Prepend[Accumulate[PadRight[offset, k, offset]], 0];
   Take[lst, #] & /@ TakeWhile[
           Transpose[{offs + 1, offs + PadRight[scts, k + 1, scts]}], 
           Apply[And, Thread[# <= n]] &]] /; Length[scts] == Length[offset]

multisegment[lst_List, scts:{__Integer?Positive}] := 
 multisegment[lst, scts, scts] /; Mod[Length[lst], Total[scts]] == 0
```

Comment: Seems to fail if the partition list is not the same length as the offset list. e.g. `multisegment[Range[24], {2, 4}, {3, 2, 4}]` or `multisegment[Range[24], {3, 2, 4}, {2, 4}]`

Comment: plus this `multisegment[Range[24], {3, 2, 4}, {3, 2, 4}]` returns an answer but it is incomplete.

Comment: @Mike, Re: the first, I didn't set out to go for the case of the partition list and offset list not having the same length (hence the `Length[p] == Length[os]` condition). I have already upvoted your answer even before your generalization, though. Re: the second, it's an incommensurate case that I had not accounted for and is thus a bug; I'll think of a fix.

Comment: I've gone with polishing your version, Mike. :)

Comment: Getting rid of `Inner` seems to speed it up. I am going to add that to mine :). Not noticing any speed improvement using `TakeWhile` instead of `DeleteCases` ...in fact that seems to slow it down a bit. And given that `DeleteCases` is a bit easier to read I will stick with that.

Comment: @Mike doesn't it make sense for the partition and offset lists to be the same length?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard since at the time I did not know what the OP intended to do it seemed unreasonable to make any assumptions of my own (these should be explicit in the question) -- and even after finding out what this is for it is not obvious to me that more general examples should be excluded. Also, I have an example of unequal lengths in my answer. Who is to say someone may not need to produce lists like that? ...and it is no extra work in the code to do it.

Comment: @Mike: I was patterning after `Partition[]`, so I thought it was somewhat granted that the case I'm after has the partition lists and offset lists having the same length. Again, it's good that you generalized further, but I am content with the same-length scenario.