# Combinatorics: Placed errors

Tags: performance-tuning, combinatorics

Consider a vector of length `n` where each element can take one of the values `U`, `X`, `Y` or `Z`. Then define w as the the number of `X`, `Y` and `Z`'s in the vector.
How can I efficiently write a *Mathematica* function `ErrorOps[n,w]` that returns all possible strings for a particular choice of `w` and `n`?

My key concern is efficiency, since I have made three attempts that are working, but doing so too slowly.

Input:

```
n=3, w=2
```

Output:

```
ErrorOps[3, 2] = {{U, X, X}, {X, U, X}, {X, X, U}, {U, X, Y}, {X, U, Y}, {X, Y, U},
     {U, X, Z}, {X, U, Z}, {X, Z, U}, {U, Y, X}, {Y, U, X}, {Y, X, U}, {U, Y, Y},
     {Y, U, Y}, {Y, Y, U}, {U, Y, Z}, {Y, U, Z}, {Y, Z, U}, {U, Z, X}, {Z, U, X}, 
     {Z, X, U}, {U, Z, Y}, {Z, U, Y}, {Z, Y, U}, {U, Z, Z}, {Z, U, Z}, {Z, Z, U}}
```

The number of such vectors is thus `Binomial[n, w] 3^w`.

A typical function call will have `n = 10` in my case, and `w < 11`.

Comment: Related: [(5036)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5036/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I propose:

```
errorOps[n_, w_] :=
  Module[{masks, tup},
    masks = Permutations[Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ {{1, w}, {0, n - w}}];
    tup = ArrayPad[{"X", "Y", "Z"} ~Tuples~ {w}, {0, {1, 0}}, "U"];
    Join @@ Map[tup[[All, #]] &, 1 + masks (Accumulate /@ masks)]
  ]

errorOps[10, 7] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0406705, 262440}
> ```

An alternate formulation that is faster in some cases but slower in others:

```
errorOps2[n_, w_] :=
  Module[{mask, tup},
    mask = Join @@ ConstantArray @@@ {{0, n - w}, {1, w}};
    tup = GatherBy[{"X", "Y", "Z"} ~Tuples~ {w}, Sort][[All, 1]];
    tup = ArrayPad[tup, {0, {1, 0}}, "U"];
    Join @@ Permutations /@ tup[[ All, 1 + Accumulate @ mask ]]
  ]

errorOps2[10, 7] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.0335602, 262440}
> ```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution seems to be the fastest, in regard to my question. I am very happy about both answers

Comment: @Creeper  Thanks for the Accept.  I think you will be pleased with the update I just made.

Comment: I have a feeling `GatherBy[{"X", "Y", "Z"} ~Tuples~ {w}, Sort][[All, 1]]` can be written more efficiently.  (I don't mean `DeleteDuplicatesBy`.)  I'll try to come back to this.

Answer (score 5):

Is this faster than the fastest of yours?

```
xyz = {"X", "Y", "Z"};
ErrorOps[n_, w_] := Flatten[With[{tups = Tuples[xyz, w], R = Range[n]},
Table[R /. Join[Thread[Complement[R, i] -> j], Thread[i -> "U"]],
{i, Subsets[R, {n - w}]}, {j, tups}]], 1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes it was faster than my fastest one.

Comment: Coolwater: you have my vote, however you may be interested in the difference in performance between our code.  For example using `Part` to extract elements is faster than replacement and using `All` allows us to extract from all tuples at once.