# List of the combinations of more lists via permutations

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation, concatenation

I would like to generate a list of all the possible combinations of two lists. As for instance, given L=3;

```
list={0,1,2};
```

I would like to obtain the list
    {{0,0,0},{0,0,1},{0,0,2},{0,1,0},{0,2,0},{1,0,0},{2,0,0}}

I did it with the code:

```
f[d_, L_] := Module[{l, st},
   l = Join[{d}, Table[0, {j, L - 1}]];
   st = {};
   AppendTo[st, Permutations@l];
   Return[First@st];
   ];

d = 2;
L = 3;
Flatten[Join[Table[f[j, L], {j, 0, d}]], 1]
```

Is there a better way to do by combining lists?

Comment: What two lists?

Comment: Related: [(41614)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41614/121), [(82801)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82801/121), [(138472)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138472/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Starting over* I just realized that for the example given we can do this simply with [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html):

```
f2[d_, L_] := 
  Range[d] ~KroneckerProduct~ IdentityMatrix[L] // Prepend[#, 0*First@#] &

f2[2, 3]
```

> (*  {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}}  *)

```
f2[86, 99] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> (*  {0.00445, 8515}  *)

If you will accept your output in the form of a [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) this can be made more than an order of magnitude faster:

```
f3[d_, L_] := 
  Range[d] ~KroneckerProduct~ IdentityMatrix[L, SparseArray] // Prepend[#, 0*First@#] &

f3[86, 99] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> (*  {0.000288, 8515}  *)

Compare the performance of kglr's method, e.g.:

```
fx[d_, L_] :=
 With[{list = Range[0, d], list2 = ConstantArray[0, L - 1]}, 
  Sort[Join @@ (Permutations[Join[list2, {#}]] & /@ list)]
  ]

fx[86, 99] // Length // RepeatedTiming
```

> (*  {0.05107, 8515}  *)

Comment: Thank you so much...it works perfectly!

Comment: I changed the Prepend part to // Prepend[ConstantArray[0, {L}]]...it seems it goes just a bit faster

Comment: @Galuoises You're welcome.  By the way if order matters and you want a different one try `KroneckerProduct[IdentityMatrix[L], Range[d]]\[Transpose] // Prepend[#, ConstantArray[0, L]] &`

Answer (score 5):

```
list = {0, 1, 2};
list2 = {0, 0};
Sort[Join @@ (Permutations[Join[list2, {#}]] & /@ list)]
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}}

Answer (score 0):

```
Permutations[{0, 0, #}, {3}] & /@ Range[0, 2] // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

**Original Answer**

```
Permutations /@ IntegerDigits[Range[0, 2], 2 + 1, 3] // Join @@ # &
```

> {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 0}, {2,
>      0, 0}}

Comment: No need for `, {3}` in` `Permutations` that I can see, as that is implicit I think?