# How would I add together any list of arguments as a pure function?

Tags: functions

Let's say I have a list of arguments, of any length.

How would I add them all together?

```
f = Evaluate[Plus @@ Array[Slot, 3]] &
f[1, 2, 3]
```

This would add together 3 numbers, but how would I add together any amount of numbers?

Answer (score 5):

See [`SlotSequence`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SlotSequence.html).  I would use:

```
f = +## &

f[1, 2, 3]
```

> ```
> 6
> ```

The long form:

```
InputForm[f]
```

> ```
> Plus[##1] &
> ```

Other forms would be:

```
Total @ {##} &

Tr @ {##} &

Plus @@ {##} &
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I'm interpreting your question correctly, but the most obvious way is just

```
f = Plus;
f[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I assume that there is a deeper *use case* behind your question, so when you clarify what you like to achieve, maybe someone can give you better tips.