# How to understand the extensional usage of Flatten?

Tags: programming, list-manipulation

Recently, I have been reading *Mathematica* program that written by many advanced *Mathematica* user, like **Mr.Wizard, J.M., Kuba,etc** to improve my programming capacity

In the [On generalizing Partition[] (with offsets) to sublists of unequal length](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/975/on-generalizing-partition-with-offsets-to-sublists-of-unequal-length/1021?noredirect=1#comment170365_1021)

I read the program of **Mr.Wizard** about `dpCyclic`which owns a line code shown as below:

```
MapThread[blocks[[All, # ;; #2]] &, ranges] ~Flatten~ {2, 1}
```

I cannot under the useage of `Flatten[list,{2,1}]`

So I look up the **Wolfram Help Documentation**

> [image]

And it has a example:

```
u = {{a, b}, {c, d}};
Flatten[{{u, 0 u}, {0 u, u}}, {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}] // MatrixForm
```

> [image]

Or

```
Flatten[{{1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7}}, {{2}, {1}}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}, {5, 6}, {7}}

However,I cannot understand their result correctly.

**So my question is :**

1.How to understand extensional usage of **`Flatten`**?

2.In `Flatten[{{1}, {2, 3}, {3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7}}, {{2}, {1}}]`,how to use the argument 
`{{2}, {1}}` correctly, Namely, why I cannot use `{{2}, {2}}`?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand it is used as follows:
The mentioned example:

```
Flatten[list, {{2}, {1}}]
```

takes of all elements in list first the first elements (s_{1,j} building the first new list). This leads to: {1, 2, 3, 4}, then (from the remaining) lists the next elements -> {3, 4, 5}, then the third: {5, 6}, an lastly, the fourth, the list {7}.

Greetings from Germany

Mike