# Drawing a trihexagonal tiling

Tags: graphics, lattices

I am trying to draw a trihexagonal tiling of the following form

[image]

using *Mathematica*. I attempted to begin by using the result given in [this  Stack Overflow Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787928/how-to-draw-a-triangular-grid-of-length-n-in-mathematica). However, I couldn't figure out how to get it to work by placing adjacent hexagons into the triangles.

Could anyone perhaps present an easy version of a code using `Graphics3D` to generate this kind of lattice?

Comment: Please add the code from the attempt you have been working on.

Comment: Your link show a 2D tiling. What has this question to do with `Graphics3D`?

Comment: Sorry, it could be done in 2d, and I could generalize it to 3d easily.

Comment: [A Gravatar from a long time ago...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b2npM.png)

Answer (score 16):

```
unitcell[i_, j_] := Translate[
  {Line[{{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
   Line[{{1/4, Sqrt[3]/4}, {1/2, 0}}],
   Line[{{1, Sqrt[3]/2}, {5/4, Sqrt[3]/4}}], PointSize[Large],
   Point[{{0, 0}, {1/4, Sqrt[3]/4}, {1/2, 0}}]},
  {i + j/2, Sqrt[3]/2 j}]

Graphics[Array[unitcell, {5, 5}]]
```

> [image: tiling]

Comment: You might also consider getting the coordinates from an Entity:
```kagome = Entity["PeriodicTiling", "TrihexagonalTiling"];
pgons = kagome["PrimitiveUnit"] // Cases[#, _Polygon, Infinity] &;
{vec1, vec2} = kagome["TranslationVectors"][];
unitcell[i_, j_] := Translate[pgons, i*vec1 + j*vec2];
Graphics[{Opacity[0.1], EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.3]], Array[unitcell, {5, 5}]}];```

Answer (score 15):

Just for fun:

```
c[p_, m_, n_, v_] := 
 Join @@ CoordinateBoundingBoxArray[{p, p + {m, n} v}, v]
tile[m_, n_] := 
 With[{pts = 
    CirclePoints[{##}, 1, 6] & @@@ 
     Join @@ (c[#, m, n, {2, 2 Sqrt[3]}] & /@ {{0, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]}})},
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], FaceForm[White], Polygon /@ pts, 
    PointSize[0.01], Point /@ pts}, ImageSize -> 400]
  ]
```

So `tile[20,5]`

[image]

Now to make torus:

```
tor[u_, v_, m_, n_] := {(m + n Cos[v]) Cos[u], (m + n Cos[v]) Sin[u], 
  n Sin[v]}
f[x_, m_, n_] := Rescale[x, {m, n}, {0, 2 Pi}]
torp[m_, n_, a_, b_] := 
 With[{pts = 
    CirclePoints[{##}, 1, 6] & @@@ 
     Join @@ (c[#, m, n, {2, 2 Sqrt[3]}] & /@ {{0, 0}, {1, Sqrt[3]}})},
  Map[tor[f[#[[1]], -1, 2 m + 2], 
     f[#[[2]], -Sqrt[3]/2, (4 n + 3) Sqrt[3]/2], a, b] &, pts, {2}]]
gv[m_, n_] := 
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{Red, Thick}], FaceForm[None], 
   Polygon /@ torp[m, n, (2 m + 3)/(2 Pi), (4 n + 3) Pi/(4 Pi)], 
   Yellow, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point /@ torp[m, n, (2 m + 3)/(2 Pi), (4 n + 3) Pi/(4 Pi)]}, 
  Background -> Black, Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 400]
```

Visualizing:

```
Manipulate[
 Row[{tile[p, q], gv[p, q]}], {p, Range[10, 40, 10]}, {q, 
  Range[3, 11, 2]}]
```

[image]

Apologies for coloring.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not quite yet willing to reveal how I did the fancy woven 籠目 torus in my comment, but I will at least reveal how to make a `GraphicsComplex[]` object for this lattice. (I in fact asked [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/975) as I needed the function in the course of building Archimedean lattices.)

```
multisegment[lst_List, scts_List] := Block[{acc},
  acc = Prepend[Accumulate[PadRight[scts, Length[lst]/Mean[scts], scts]], 0];
  Inner[Take[lst, {#1, #2}] &, Most[acc] + 1, Rest[acc], List]]

kagome[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] := GraphicsComplex[Flatten[
            Table[If[EvenQ[j] && EvenQ[k], Unevaluated[Sequence[]],
                     {j + (k - 3)/2, (k - 1) Sqrt[3]/2}],
                  {k, 2 n + 1}, {j, 2 m + 1}], 1], 
            Polygon[Flatten[
                    Apply[{Append[Most[#1], First[#2]], 
                           Flatten[Riffle[#2, {Rest[#1], Reverse[Most[#3]]}]], 
                           Prepend[Rest[#3], Last[#2]]} &, 
                          Transpose /@ Partition[MapIndexed[
                          With[{l = Mod[First[#2], 2]},
                               Partition[#1, l + 2, l + 1]] &, 
                          Most[multisegment[Range[(n + 1) (3 m + 2)],
                                            {2 m + 1, m + 1}]]], 3, 2],
                          {2}], 2]]]
```

Test:

```
Graphics[{Directive[FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Black]], kagome[5, 3]}]
```

[image: small 籠目 lattice]

To embed this on a torus while preserving the angles, one needs a *conformal* map. I'll use the one from [this paper](http://bridgesmathart.org/2011/cdrom/proceedings/134/index.html):

```
torus[s_, t_][{u_, v_}] := {s Cos[2 π u/s], s Sin[2 π u/s], 
                            t Sin[2 π v/t]}/(Sqrt[s^2 + t^2] - t Cos[2 π v/t])

With[{m = 24, n = 12}, 
     Graphics3D[MapAt[Map[torus[2 m, n Sqrt[3]], N[#]] &, kagome[m, n], 1], 
                Boxed -> False]]
```

[image: 籠目 torus]

Comment: @J.M. Thank you for this wonderful answer +1, esp torus...:)

Answer (score 5):

```
ClearAll[triHex];
triHex[w_, h_] := Module[{hex = {FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Black], PointSize[Large], 
 Polygon @ #, Red, Point @ #} & @ CirclePoints[6]}, 
Translate[hex, Join @@ Table[{2 j + i, i Sqrt[3]}, {i, 0, h - 1}, {j, 0, w - 1}]]]
```

**Examples:**

```
Graphics[triHex[10, 5], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[triHex[7, 7] /. White -> LightBlue, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]