# Creating MeshRegions of various 2D lattices

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, mesh, lattices

This is a soft question about the best approach to design a function that creates `MeshRegion` objects of various 2D lattices, e.g. kagome or hexagonal, all through one consistent interface.

A reasonable approach is to provide a unit cell as a `Polygon`, along with translation vectors. This is what many solutions on this site use, e.g.

- [Drawing a trihexagonal tiling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89138/12)
- [Making a 2D hexagonal mesh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109479/12)

The problem is that `MeshRegion` expects a set of points, then a set of polygons that refer to those points by *index*. Neighbouring cells of the lattice will share some of these points.  Thus it is not simple to compute the translation of points: after translating the coordinates, we must check if some of the translated ones coincide with ones we already had.  Doing this is also likely to result in a "messy" indexing of the points. Ideally, they should be indexed in a consistent order.

Here's an example to show what I mean, using [`hexTile`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109479/making-a-2d-hexagonal-mesh):

```
DiscretizeGraphics[
 Graphics@Flatten@hexTile[3, 5],
 MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Other than the messy indexing, I am not happy to use `DiscretizeGraphics`. It is an extremely general function which must handle lots of different inputs. Such functions in Mathematica are not always very robust. Will it always correctly identify points which are the same?  What if the coordinates are floating point? Even `ConvexHullMesh` won't always detect collinear points, not even with exact coordinates.

How would you approach this problem?  There are several potential solutions. I am looking for "clean" ones which perform well and are not too complicated to implement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I modify [`hexTile`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109482/38178) slightly for convenience by skipping the wrapup with `Polygon` and by `Flatten`ing a level.

```
hexTile1[n_, m_] := 
  With[{hex = 
     Table[{Cos[2. Pi k/6] + #, Sin[2. Pi k/6] + #2}, {k, 6}] &}, 
   Flatten[Table[hex[3 i + 3 ((-1)^j + 1)/4, Sqrt[3]/2 j], {i, n}, {j, m}], 1]];
```

Let's assume that we have a ragged array `polygonpts` whose entries are lists containing the vertex positions of each polygon. 
First, we compute a clustering tolerance `ϵ` lower than any edge length in the tesselation. Second, we cluster duplicates with the help of `Nearest` in order to produce a reduced point set `newpts`. Afterwards, we use the `NearestFunction` of `newpts` as a lookup function for the vertex indices.

```
polygonpts = hexTile1[3, 5];
ϵ = 0.5 Min[Sqrt[Total[(# - RotateLeft[#])^2, {2}]] & /@ polygonpts];
pts = Flatten[polygonpts, 1];
plist = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[
   Compile[{{idx, _Integer, 1}}, 
    Min[idx],
    RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
    Parallelization -> True
    ][Nearest[pts -> Automatic, pts, {∞, ϵ}]]
   ]];
newpts = pts[[plist]];
nf = Nearest[newpts -> Automatic];
polygons = Internal`PartitionRagged[Flatten[nf[pts]], Length /@ polygonpts];

MeshRegion[newpts, Polygon[polygons], MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}]
```

[image]

It appears that this is the same mesh as the one returned by `DiscretizeGraphics`.

Sorting the reduced point set first leads to somewhat nicer enumeration of points:

```
newpts = Sort[pts[[plist]]];
nf = Nearest[newpts -> Automatic];
polygons = Internal`PartitionRagged[Flatten[nf[pts]], Length /@ polygonpts];

MeshRegion[newpts, Polygon[polygons], MeshCellLabel -> {0 -> "Index"}]
```

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hU46N.png :-)

Comment: Beautiful! My favorite is the one in the center of the bottom row! (Btw., looking for so long onto this particular one, I found some disturbances in its color pattern at the upper right corner.)

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification of `hexMesh[]` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/85901) can generate hexagonal `MeshRegion[]` objects:

```
(* https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/975 *)
multisegment[lst_List, scts : {__Integer?Positive}, offset : {__Integer?Positive}] :=
             Module[{n = Length[lst], k, offs},
                    k = Ceiling[n/Mean[offset]];
                    offs = Prepend[Accumulate[PadRight[offset, k, offset]], 0];
                    Take[lst, #] & /@ 
                    TakeWhile[Transpose[{offs + 1, offs + PadRight[scts, k + 1, scts]}],
                              Apply[And, Thread[# <= n]] &]] /;
             Length[scts] == Length[offset];

multisegment[lst_List, scts : {__Integer?Positive}] := 
             multisegment[lst, scts, scts] /; Mod[Length[lst], Total[scts]] == 0

hexMesh[n_Integer, m_Integer] := 
   MeshRegion[Flatten[Delete[NestList[TranslationTransform[{0, Sqrt[3]}], 
                                      FoldList[Plus, {-1, Sqrt[3]}/2,
                                               Table[AngleVector[-π Sin[k π/2]/3],
                                                     {k, 4 n + 1}]], m],
                             {{1, -1}, {-1, 1}}], 1], 
              Polygon[Flatten[{multisegment[#1, {4, 2}, {3, 1}], 
                               Reverse[multisegment[Rest[#2], {2, 4}, {1, 3}], 2]} & @@@ 
                              Partition[Join[{PadRight[Range[4 n + 1], 4 n + 2]}, 
                                             Partition[Range[4 n + 2, m (4 n + 2) - 1],
                                                       4 n + 2],
                                             {PadLeft[m (4 n + 2) - 1 + Range[4 n + 1],
                                                      4 n + 2]}], 2, 1],
                              {{1, 3}, {2, 4}}]]]

hexMesh[3, 4]
```

[image: hexagonal mesh]

Answer (score 1):

The method for generating the 籠目 lattice in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89163) can straightforwardly be converted to something that generates `MeshRegion[]` objects (`multisegment[]` is defined in [my other answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/183254)):

```
kagomeMesh[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] := 
      MeshRegion[Flatten[Table[If[EvenQ[j] && EvenQ[k], Nothing,
                                  {j + (k - 3)/2, (k - 1) Sqrt[3]/2}],
                               {k, 2 n + 1}, {j, 2 m + 1}], 1], 
                 Polygon[Flatten[Apply[{Append[Most[#], First[#2]], 
                                        Flatten[Riffle[#2, {Rest[#], Reverse[Most[#3]]}]], 
                                        Prepend[Rest[#3], Last[#2]]} &, 
                                       Transpose[Partition[MapIndexed[
                         With[{l = Mod[First[#2], 2]}, Partition[#, l + 2, l + 1]] &,
                         Most[multisegment[Range[(n + 1) (3 m + 2)], {2 m + 1, m + 1}]]],
                         3, 2], {1, 3, 2}], {2}], 2]]]

kagomeMesh[5, 3]
```

[image: kagome MeshRegion]