# Crop a Voronoi diagram and get a proper MeshRegion

Tags: regions, computational-geometry, mesh

How can I crop a [`VoronoiMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VoronoiMesh.html) (or any similar `MeshRegion`) to a non-rectangular region and receive the output as a `MeshRegion` that properly encodes cell-adjacency information?

Example:

```
voronoi = VoronoiMesh@RandomPoint[Disk[], 100];
```

I would like to crop this to the following disk, or an approximation of it as a polygon (i.e. `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Disk[]`)

```
Show[voronoi, Graphics@Circle[]]
```

[image]

The output should *look* like this, but be a correct `MeshRegion`:

```
pieces = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[Disk[], #] & /@ MeshPrimitives[voronoi, 2]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {29.715, Null} *)
```

This is much too slow at 30 seconds and only 100 cells. The solution should work for thousands of cells.

```
Show[pieces]
```

[image]

This result is not a `MeshRegion`. The pieces *could* be assembled into one, but doing so is non-trivial as it is important that no point is duplicated, i.e. when vertices of neighbouring polygons coincide, they should be represented with a single point. One way to do this is the [technique based on `Nearest` shown by Henrik Schumacher](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171998/12).

---

A more general formulation of the question would be:

Given a `MeshRegion` in 2D or 3D and a `BoundaryMeshRegion` of the same dimensionality, how can we crop all cells of the `MeshRegion` to be contained within the `BoundaryMeshRegion`?

Note that the naïve

```
RegionIntersection[voronoi, BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@Disk[]]
```

will not preserve the internal cells of the `MeshRegion`.

Comment: [This related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31187/12) does not discuss obtaining the result as a MeshRegion (and is also slow).

Comment: The answer to [this question (Making a Voronoi diagram bounded by the convex hull)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111755/27951) is also related: it does obtain the result as a `MeshRegion`, it is faster than your original approach, but it is slower than those shown here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**First Try (doesn't work due to a bug)**

That's very frustrating. I thought that it might be a good idea to discretize the disk first and compute the intersections afterwards. That improves the timing by a factor of 20 but it gets some of the intersections wrong.

```
disk = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01];
cells = MeshPrimitives[voronoi, 2];
pieces2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[disk, #] & /@ cells; // AbsoluteTiming // First
Show[
 Cases[pieces2, _BoundaryMeshRegion],
 Graphics[{Red,
   Extract[cells, 
    Position[pieces2, Except[_BoundaryMeshRegion], 1, Heads -> False]]
   }]
 ]
```

> 1.45424

This is the result by Mmm 11.3. The intersections of the red cells with the circle could not be computed (probably a bug?):

[image]

**Second Try**

Not as simple anymore but quite efficient and maybe sufficiently general.

Let's say `R` is a `MeshRegion` and `B` is `BoundaryMeshRegion`. We want to crop `R` to be contained in `B`.

The strategy: Cells of `R` are divided into three groups: `internalcells`  which are entirely contained in `B`, `externalcells` which do not intersect with `B`, and the `bndcells` which intersect the boundary. The `internalcells` can just be copied, the `externalcells` get discarded and the `bndcells` are *first* discretized by `BoundaryDiscretizeRegion` and then intersected with `B`. In the end, everythng is merged by the [method that you fortunately mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171998/38178). (I completely forgot about that post). Note that also `IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix` comes in handy here, in counting the number of vertices of each cell that lie within `B`. Note however that this is guaranteed to work correctly **only  if each cell of `R` is also convex** (a mild condition) and **if `B` is also convex** (a more restrictive condition).

```
Needs["IGraphM`"];
cropRegion[R_MeshRegion, B_BoundaryMeshRegion] := 
 Module[{f, pts, cells, booleans, A, intersec, internalcells, 
   externalcells, bndcells, bndpieces, ϵ, plist, newpts, nf, 
   cellprimitives, celldata},
  f = RegionMember[B];
  pts = MeshCoordinates[R];
  cellprimitives = MeshPrimitives[R, 2];
  booleans = Map[Boole@*f, pts];
  
  A = IGMeshCellAdjacencyMatrix[R, 2, 0];
  intersec = (A.booleans);
  
  internalcells = Flatten[Position[Subtract[intersec, Total[A, {2}]], 0]];
  externalcells = Flatten[Position[intersec, 0]];
  bndcells = Complement[Range[Length[A]], internalcells, externalcells];
  
  bndpieces = ParallelMap[
     RegionIntersection[B, With[{p = #[[1]]}, BoundaryMesh@MeshRegion[p, Head[#][Range[Length[p]]]]]] &, 
     cellprimitives[[bndcells]]
     ];
  
  celldata = Join[
    Join @@ (MeshPrimitives[#, 2] & /@ bndpieces)[[All, All, 1]],
    cellprimitives[[internalcells, 1]]
    ];
  ϵ = 0.5 Min[
     PropertyValue[{R, 1}, MeshCellMeasure],
     PropertyValue[{#, 1}, MeshCellMeasure] & /@ bndpieces
     ]; 
  pts = Flatten[celldata, 1]; 
  plist = Sort[DeleteDuplicates[
     Compile[{{idx, _Integer, 1}}, 
       Min[idx], 
       RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
       Parallelization -> True
       ][Nearest[pts -> Automatic, pts, {∞, ϵ}]]
     ]]; 
  newpts = pts[[plist]]; nf = Nearest[newpts -> Automatic]; 
  cells = Internal`PartitionRagged[Flatten[nf[pts]], Length /@ celldata];
  MeshRegion[newpts, Polygon[cells]]
  ];
```

**Usage example and timing**

```
voronoi = VoronoiMesh@RandomPoint[Disk[], 10000];
r = 1;
disk = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[{0, 0}, r], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01];
S = cropRegion[voronoi, disk]; // RepeatedTiming // First
S
```

> 0.416

[image]

The original Voronoi mesh with 100 cells gets processed in about `0.04` seconds. That's about 700 times as fast as what we have started from.

There is still some optimization potential since we do not really need to search the interior vertices of the interior region for duplicates...

**Warning**

If `B` is not convex, then some less pleasant things can happen. For example, using this star fish

```
B = BoundaryMeshRegion[
  Map[t \[Function] (2 + Cos[5 t])/3 {Cos[t], Sin[t]}, Most@Subdivide[0., 2. Pi, 2000]],
  Line[Partition[Range[2000], 2, 1, 1]]
  ]
```

[image]

can lead to

```
SeedRandom[17];
cropRegion[VoronoiMesh@RandomPoint[Disk[], 100], B]
```

[image]

But this becomes more and more negligible, the smaller the cells in `R` are:

```
cropRegion[VoronoiMesh@RandomPoint[Disk[], 10000], B]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
pieces2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ 
  (Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[#, Polygon[CirclePoints[100]]] &/@ 
    MeshPrimitives[voronoi, 2]); // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 1.09499

(vs 33.0193 for `pieces = ...`)

```
Show[pieces2]
```

[image]

With 1000 points it takes `11.3679` seconds to get `pieces2`, and `Show[pieces2]` gives:

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Here's another implementation based on the idea of grabbing cells fully contained in the disk and intersecting the ones with partial overlap.

```
maskedMeshRegion[mr_?MeshRegionQ, mask_?ConstantRegionQ, δ_:0.01] :=
  Block[{prims, inside, frontier, bmr, fpieces, pts, cells},
    prims = MeshPrimitives[mr, 2];

    inside = Select[prims, RegionWithin[mask, #]&];

    frontier = Select[Complement[prims, inside], !RegionDisjoint[mask, #]&];
    bmr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[mask, MaxCellMeasure -> δ];
    fpieces = RegionIntersection[bmr, 
      BoundaryMeshRegion[#, Line[Append[Range[Length[#]], 1]]]]& /@ frontier[[All, 1]];

    pts = Union[Join @@ MeshCoordinates /@ fpieces, Join @@ inside[[All, 1]]];
    cells = Join[
      Join @@ (MeshPrimitives[#, 2]& /@ fpieces), 
      inside
    ] /. Dispatch[Thread[pts -> Range[Length[pts]]]];

    MeshRegion[pts, cells]
]
```

A test:

```
voronoi = VoronoiMesh@RandomPoint[Disk[], 10000];
maskedMeshRegion[voronoi, Disk[]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]