# How to add 'border' to Voronoi diagram

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

Suppose I have a set of points `pts`, from which I generate a Voronoi diagram `VD`:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
VD = Show[VoronoiMesh[pts], Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Now, as per the geometric transformation made with `Voronoiesh[]`, we can observe that the area of the "outer" cells project themselves indefinitely until their edges intersect with another cell, so their area is much larger than that of the 'interior' cells.

My question is, how could I 'bound' the Voronoi diagram so that the outer cells have roughly the same area as the interior ones?

I'm thinking that a possible solution would require generating a 'mask' that bounds the region covered by `pts`, and then excluding the area outside this mask. I was thinking of generating such a mask as the merge of circles centered at each point, with a radius producing roughly the same area as the interior points.

A second solution I've been thinking of is to generate some excess of points `ptsOuter`, which cover an area external to the area within `pts`, roughly equally spaced than the `pts`. Then, make the Voronoi mesh on the set {pts, ptsOuter}, which I'd think would bound the points in `pts` by using the points in `ptsOuter`.

I am wondering if there is an easier or more efficient way than these ideas I currently have.

Thanks!

**Edit:** By 'border' I mean a limit that follows the distribution of the points in `pts`, imagine something like this at the end (the drawn border here, which would exclude the area outside it):

[image]

Comment: Related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31187/cropping-a-voronoi-diagram?rq=1

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/175366

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update 2:** An alternative way to specify the cropping region:

```
ClearAll[bsf, explode]
bsf = BSplineFunction[outerpoints[[FindShortestTour[outerpoints][[2]]]], 
   SplineDegree -> Automatic, SplineClosed -> True];

explode[f_] := f[#] + {{0, -#2}, {#2, 0}}.Normalize[f'[t] /. t -> #] &;

borderpoly = Polygon[explode[bsf][#, .2] & /@ Subdivide[100]];

pieces2 = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.25,  RandomColor[]]] & /@ 
  (Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[#, borderpoly] & /@ 
     MeshPrimitives[vm, 2]);

Show[pieces2, Graphics[{Red, Point[pts], Purple, PointSize[Medium], 
   Point @ outerpoints}], ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

Use `explode[bsf][#, .4] &` when defining `borderpoly` to get

[image]

**Update:** Cropping frontier polygons and lines:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
vm = VoronoiMesh[pts];

mc = MeshCells[VoronoiMesh[pts], {1 | 2, "Frontier"}];

intm = RegionDifference[vm, MeshRegion[MeshCoordinates[vm], mc]];

borderpolygon = MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
     TransformedRegion[intm, ScalingTransform[1.3 {1, 1}]]], 2][[1]];

pieces = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[#, 
  BaseStyle -> Opacity[.25, RandomColor[]]] & /@ 
    (Graphics`PolygonUtils`PolygonIntersection[#, borderpolygon] & /@ 
       MeshPrimitives[vm, 2]);

outerpoints = Select[pts, Not @* RegionMember[intm]];

Row[{Show[vm, pieces, Graphics[{Red, Point[pts], Purple, PointSize[Medium], 
    Point @ outerpoints}], ImageSize -> Medium], 
  Show[pieces, Graphics[{Red, Point[pts], Purple, PointSize[Medium], 
    Point @ outerpoints}], ImageSize -> Medium]}]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

You can use the second argument of `VoronoiMesh` to specify coordinate bounds:

```
SeedRandom[1]
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];

Show[VoronoiMesh[pts, 1.1 {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], Graphics[{Red, Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: .@kglr the issue is how to get these points so that they follow the 'border' of my points. I added a small edit to the question.

Comment: .@kglr thanks! The answer by @flinty is closer to what I was thinking of, but it uses a convex hull, which would obscure 'dents' in a blob of points, highlighting only the 'protrusions'. So, my hand-drawn boundary currently is my best illustration of the ideal solution to the problem.

Comment: Great. The update 2 is exactly what I was looking for. Could you elaborate a bit on what does 'explode' do? I can read the code, but is hard to guess what the logic behind it is. Thanks!

Comment: If I follow correctly, it finds the shortest tour of the boundary points and creates a smooth BSpline bubble going through them.The 'explode' inflates that bubble in the direction of the normal vector to the spline. Really clever.

Comment: Thank you @flinty. That's exactly what  the combination of `bsf` & `explode` does. `ScalingTransform` in the first update has the limitation to work in two directions only. Working with the normal vector we avoid this limitation.

Comment: .@kglr, how/where can I calculate the area of the resulting cells after this transformation?

Comment: @TumbiSapichu, you can use `Area /@ pieces2`

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this in [Cropping a Voronoi diagram](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31187/cropping-a-voronoi-diagram?rq=1) but the result is a bit ugly

```
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {100, 2}];
vmsh = VoronoiMesh[pts];

poly2disk[cell_, radius_] := 
 Block[{pts = MeshPrimitives[cell, 0][[All, 1]]},
  Return[Disk[Mean[pts], radius]]
 ]
disks = DiscretizeRegion[
   RegionUnion[poly2disk[#, 0.3] & /@ MeshPrimitives[vmsh, 2]]];

DeleteCases[
  RegionIntersection[DiscretizeGraphics@#, disks] & /@ 
   MeshPrimitives[vmsh, 2], _RegionIntersection] // 
 RegionPlot[#, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &
```

[image: disks clipping voronoi mesh]

You could also mask the mesh with the convex hull if you're happy with the points lying on the edge having no space around them. Here I show the result on top.

```
cvxh=ConvexHullMesh[pts];
Show[
 vmsh,
 DeleteCases[
   RegionIntersection[DiscretizeGraphics@#, cvxh] & /@ 
    MeshPrimitives[vmsh, 2], _RegionIntersection] // 
  RegionPlot[#, AspectRatio -> Automatic] &
 ,
 Graphics[Point[pts]]
 ]
```

[image: voronoi mesh with convex hull]

Maybe scaling up the new mesh about the center of all points would expand the convex hull enough to include some space around the edges too if that's desired.

Comment: This is something closer to what I was thinking about. The only problem I see is that my points usually are blobs with protrusions/depressions, so the convex hull would mask the 'depressions' in the shape, only highlighting the protrusions.

Comment: With respect to masking by the convex hull, see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111755) as well.