# Partition a list into sublists of unequal lengths according to a list of lengths

Tags: list-manipulation

This is a conscious duplicate of [On generalizing Partition[] (with offsets) to sublists of unequal length](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/975/35000):  it was seven years ago, and all answers are quite involved; maybe something easier has been added in new versions. Moreover I want a relatively simple subcase of it.

I have a list, say, `{x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9]}`, and another list prescribing lengths of sublists, say, `{3,2,4}`. I want the result

```
{x[1],x[2],x[3]}, {x[4],x[5]}, {x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9]}
```

in form of either a sequence or a list of lists.

My version:

```
myPartition[l_,s_]:=With[{a = Accumulate[Prepend[s, 0]]}, 
  Table[l[[a[[i]] + 1 ;; a[[i + 1]]]], {i, Length[s]}]
```

There must exist something more efficient I believe.

Comment: `TakeList` or the faster but not as flexible and undocumented ``Internal`PartitionRagged``.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`TakeList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TakeList.html):

```
lst = Array[x, 9];
TakeList[lst, {3, 2, 4}]
```

> {{x[1], x[2], x[3]}, {x[4], x[5]}, {x[6], x[7], x[8], x[9]}}